# Java is not purely Object Oriented - what does this mean w.r.t primitve types?

Tags: class, primitive-types

When I look at the javadocs of Class.java it says:

```
/*The primitive Java types ({@code boolean},
 * {@code byte}, {@code char}, {@code short},
 * {@code int}, {@code long}, {@code float}, and
 * {@code double}), and the keyword {@code void} are also
 * represented as {@code Class} objects.
*/
```

I had always heard that primitive types in Java are not classes/objects hence Java isn't purely Object Oriented. But the above JavaDoc confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't get confused by the term "represented" and mess up "type" and "value". The representations are created by the Java Virtual Machine, they are not instantiated for every primitive **value** (this would be [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html), though some instances are cached):

> There are nine predefined Class objects to represent the eight
>   primitive **types** and void. These are created by the Java Virtual
>   Machine, and have the same names as the primitive types that they
>   represent, namely boolean, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and
>   double.
>
> These objects may only be accessed via the following public **static**
>   final variables, and are the only Class objects for which this method
>   returns true.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isPrimitive%28%29