# Static , Dynamic, Weak, Strong types of the variable

Tags: java, type-systems

Although there are so many questions related to this topic but somehow i always feel that something i don't know or say i am not satisfied with those answers, so here i post again

```
    Integer in=new Integer(4);
    Character character=(Character) in; //Cannot cast from Integer to Character
    String s="hello";
    int j=(int) s;//Cannot Cast from string to int 
    char chi='a';
    int l=(int)chi; //works
    int i=0;
    char ch=(char)i; //works
    String b=(String)1+"hello";//cannot cast from int to string
```

in the 2nd,4th and 9th line it shows me the commented error  whereas i can make the conversion between **int** and **char**  in the line where it is commented works.

> So in the code that i have posted where the compiler checks for the static/dynamic behavior and where it check for the weak/strong behavior.

I am sure there must be so many answer of these question would  be available so if available post the link otherwise detailed explanation would be really appreciable.

> What makes me confused

- Some how both Static/Dynamic and Strong/Weak looks same to me
- How the compiler understand when to check for the Static/Dynamic types and       when to check for the Strong/Weak  types
- What are the necessity of the two kind of type checking system.

Comment: `char` and `int` are both numeric primitives, that's why that works, as `char` is represented internally as an unsigned 8 bit number, it's like casting a long to a double

Comment: There are not really two types of type checking - just a fixed set of numeric conversions that may be applicable in some situations. As to "How does the compiler know" - well, it knows because the language specification contains very clear rules for that: [Chapter 5. Conversions and Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html)

Comment: You cannot cast object to primitive type.

Comment: So   **char**, **int**, **short**,  **long** , **double**, **byte**  are all of numeric primitve types because i can make conversion in between them.@1blustone

Comment: @TaleevAalam No, char, int, short, long , double, byte are all of numeric primitve types **_so_**  you can make conversion in between them

Comment: Specification for all primitives: [4.2. Primitive Types and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)

Comment: @1blustone A `char` in Java is not 8 bits, it's 16 bits.

Comment: @jesper **A char in java is not 8 bits, its 16 bits**  how does it affect the typecasting system

Comment: @TaleevAalam this does not really matter for this question - he was just pointing out a mistake in [1bluestone's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603719/static-dynamic-weak-strong-types-of-the-variable#comment76194627_44603719)

Comment: What do you mean by "Strong" and "Weak"?

Comment: There are so many resources on the net which  describes a programing language by strongly typed and weakly typed along with statically typed and dynamically typed @bloch

Comment: Java is a strongly-typed language across the board. "Weakly typed" will never apply in Java. Likewise all references in Java are statically typed, never dynamically typed. So the compiler never needs to "understand when to check for the Static/Dynamic types and when to check for the Strong/Weak types". Such a thing just doesn't happen.

Answer (score 5):

You are totally missing the concept of Static vs Dynamic, and I have no idea what you mean by Strong vs Weak in the question, as your question seem to be about Primitives vs Objects.

Static vs Dynamic is about *method binding*, i.e. determining which method of an object to call when objects are subclassed. Your code is not calling any methods, so Static vs Dynamic is meaningless to your question.

As I said, I have no idea what you mean by Strong vs Weak. Java has the concept of Strong References and Weak References, but that is all about garbage collection, and that has nothing to do with your question.

Your question seems to be about Primitives, which are the types in all lowercase:
`byte`, `short`, `char`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, and `boolean`.
Ignoring `boolean`, which is a `true` vs `false` value, those are all numeric *value* types, i.e. they store a numeric value, and they are not *objects*.

The numeric primitive values can be assigned to each other, though a cast is necessary if the assignment might cause loss of value magnitude (called a [narrowing primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)).

*Objects* are types in mixed case, e.g. `Integer`, `Character`, `String`, etc. (User object types can be in lowercase, but that is a violation of naming standards).

Object types can be assigned to each other if they are related by subclassing, though a cast is necessary when down-casting (called a [narrowing reference conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6)).

Objects and primitive cannot be cast to each other, except for when [auto-boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) and/or [auto-unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) is involved, e.g. `int` to/from `Integer`.

Of the 3 questions at the end of your question, only the third one makes some sense, if it is rephrased as "Why does Java have primitive types?". That has been answered here: [Why do people still use primitive types in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5199359/5221149), and here: [Why are there Primitive datatype in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14477743/5221149).